# Circle json generic in trait

Tags: json, scala

I have few case classes with exacly same def:

```
def toJson : String = this.asJson.deepMerge(Json.obj(("type", Json.fromString(`type`)))).noSpaces
```

I would like move this part to trait.
For example:

```
trait Test[A] {
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[A]
  def jsonWithType[A] = this.asJson.noSpaces
}
```

But this returns me an error of course:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter encoder: io.circe.Encoder[io.outofaxis.pixelart.player.server.application.model.Test[A]]
```

Is it possible to achieve my goal ?

EDIT:

I found also workaround, in object where I need those jsons I did:

```
implicit def asJsonWithTypeNoSpaces[A <: SomeEvent](obj: A)(implicit encoder: Encoder[A]): String = {
    obj.asJson.deepMerge(Json.obj(("type", Json.fromString(obj.`type`)))).noSpaces
  }
```

And works fine

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve what you want is simply to move the implicit constraint to your method and get rid of your other `val`. After all you've probably already defined it somewhere, why force an unnecessary `override`?

```
trait Test[A] {

  // Equivalently def jsonWithType[A](implicit encoder: Encoder[A])
  def jsonWithType[A : Encoder] = this.asJson.noSpaces

}
```

If you really must sate your override needs, you can also directly pass in your encoder. Remember: implicit arguments can be satisfied explicitly.

```
trait Test[A] {

  val encoder: Encoder[A]

  def jsonWithType[A] = this.asJson(encoder).noSpaces

}
```